# Python requests module SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'x.x.x.x' doesn't match 'x.x.x.x")))

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, python-requests, ssl-certificate

I'm using the "requests" module for getting JSON from my web service, using the next code:

```
import requests
import SSL

# With or without this line of code below, the output is the same
ssl.match_hostname = lambda cert, hostname: True

response = requests.get("MY_URL", cert=("client.pem", "client-key.pem"), verify="CAcert.cer")
```

When the SSL step seems to fail with the following message:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='x.x.x.x', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: {WEBSERVICE_URL_PATTERN} (Caused by SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'x.x.x.x' doesn't match 'x.x.x.x'")))
```

I'm using Python 3.10.5 with the latest version of the "requests" module.

Does anyone know what could cause this kind of error and how to fix it?

Comment: `ssl.match_hostname` is not internally used in recent Python versions, thus overwriting it does not make sense. Also it is deprecated since Python 3.7 and will be removed in 3.12.

Comment: As I mentioned below, I've added it for skipping the step of the host matching process, which seems to fail anyway.
I removed that from my program and it keeps on failing either way.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've redacted actual names which are in fact different, because if you really did have a host named `x.x.x.x` using a cert with the same name it *would* match (unless it wasn't really the same because the CA, or a potentially-bogus 'subject'/'subscriber', used lookalike characters).

From the [documentation of `match_hostname`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#certificate-handling)

> Changed in version 3.7: The function is no longer used to TLS connections. Hostname matching is now performed by OpenSSL. ...
> Deprecated since version 3.7.

At the python.ssl level, or http.client or urllib.requests, you can still turn off only hostname checking with `check_hostname=False` in the `SSLContext`. However AFAIK `requests` doesn't give you access to the SSL level except for setting the cert(s) as you do or the sledgehammer option of turning off *all* verification with `verify=False`.

If at all possible, you should try to use a hostname and a host cert that do match. Note changing either the name you request *or* the cert can accomplish this.

Comment: First of all, thank you for helping!
I think that the match_hostname isn't the problem here, because I've added it to skip (or at least try to skip) the hostname matching process, which keeps failing.
I removed it from my code, and I keep getting the same output.

Plus, unfortunately, the option of turning off the server's verifying process is not an option, as both client and server need to verify each other on the required connection.

Comment: Matasas: the _problem_ is the URL hostname and cert not matching. In older python you could _hide_ the problem with match_hostname, but now that doesn't work so yes you get the same problem whether or not your code does match_hostname. The possible fixes are: change the URL to match the cert; change the cert to match the URL;  don't use requests; use verify=False (which you reject and I don't recommend anyway).

Comment: Oh ok, I get it now! Thanks a lot!
Do you have any recommendations for another module I can use, instead of "requests"?
Also, the server I'm trying to reach out to has no hostname, so how can I change the URL to match the cert, when the server has only IP address?

Comment: Matasas: (1) per my original answer, the builtin modules ssl http(.client) urllib(.requests) can turn off hostname checking (equivalent to what you did before with .match_hostname=dummy_always_return_true) or can instead be given server_hostname=correct_value_to_check (assuming SNI is okay); the latter two provide HTTP[S] functionality similar to requests while with the first you would need to write your own HTTP logic, which can be done but I would avoid

Comment: ... (2) if the cert has a hostname but it isn't in DNS (as available to/used by your system) you could either change/set your local DNS (i.e. something like dnsmasq or maybe systemd) to include it (possibly under a searchsuffix), or resolve it by other means like /etc/hosts depending on your system and environment; if the cert _only_ has wrong or unreachable IPaddr(s) I think you're out of luck with requests but see previous for non-requests

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved, using a Subject Alternative Name (SAN) for the server, with a value of its own IP address.
I've found out that we use [Simple-CA](https://github.com/jcmoraisjr/simple-ca), and the request of getting a signed certificate from it was with a Common Name (CN), when we don't have a domain name.
After changing the signing action to SAN instead of CN, the problem was solved.

Thanks for the helpers!